# Thread-safe collections with LRU caching in Java

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, rabbitmq

I am writing a multithreaded Rabbit MQ client in Java that will be processing files. However, I do need a fast and large pool of cache, mostly a read-only list of Maps. Data will be pulled from an SQL server upon a request, but I want also the cache to have LRU algorithm built-in.

I've found a half-functional site http://cacheonix.org that seems to deliver what I want, however the download page doesn't work properly.

Do you have any hints?

I think most of my uses will be satisfied with LinkedHashMap combined with LRU caching mechanism/wrapper, but I am asking firstly.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Comment: I haven't personally used it, but it sounds like the [Google Guava caching utilities](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/) might be useful.

Comment: [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) is my latest incarnation, after having co-authored Guava's Cache (see @Finn's link) and [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap) prior to that. Any of those should be easy to work with.

Comment: @BenManes Thank you, that looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your hands dirty to implement a cache with LRU, LinkedHashMap maybe a choice.

LinkedHashMap allows to access elements with insert order or access order(Default is insert order), which is maintained by a double-linked list.

For access order, when implementing access operations of getting or putting, the accessed element would be removed to the tail of double-linked list.

What's more, with a protected method as below, LinkedHashMap enables to extend it and customize your own strategy of removing eldest element.

```
protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest) {
        return false;
}
```

With the access order and the ability of removing eldest element, you can realize your own cache with LRU.

BTW, LinkedHashMap is not thread-safe, however, you can implement your own thread-safe getter/setter.